# Retrieving data using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am retrieving users data from Firebase using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
with the onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder.My issue is that whenever i set the FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter to start listening, it makes my FindFriendsActivity to crash. This line of code in the onStart method is the one causing the problem "adapter.startListening()" What do i do about this

This is the Find Friends Activity

```
public class FindFriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RecyclerView findFriendsRecyClerList;

private DatabaseReference usersRef;

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, findFriendsViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_find_friends );

        usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ().child ( "Users" );

        findFriendsRecyClerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById ( R.id.find_friends_recyclerview );
        findFriendsRecyClerList.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( this ) );


        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar minds = findViewById ( R.id.find_friends_toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar ( minds );
        getSupportActionBar ().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled ( true );
        getSupportActionBar ().setTitle ( "FindFriends" );



        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts> ().setQuery ( usersRef,Contacts.class ).build ();


        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Contacts, findFriendsViewHolder> (options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull findFriendsViewHolder holder , int position , @NonNull Contacts model) {


                holder.username.setText ( model.getName () );
                holder.usertown.setText ( model.getTownname () );
                Picasso.get ().load ( model.getImage () ).into ( holder.profileimage );


            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public findFriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup , int i) {


                View view = LayoutInflater.from ( viewGroup.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false );

                findFriendsViewHolder viewHolder = new findFriendsViewHolder ( view );
                return  viewHolder;

            }
        };

     findFriendsRecyClerList.setAdapter ( adapter );


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart ();

        adapter.startListening ();

    }

@Override
public void onStop(){
        super.onStop ();

        adapter.stopListening ();

}

    public static class  findFriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        TextView username, usertown;
        CircleImageView profileimage;


        public findFriendsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super ( itemView );

            username = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.user_profile_name );
            usertown = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.user_town_name );
            profileimage = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.users_profile_image );


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If the application crashes, there is an error message. Find that error message and stack trace in the logcat output of your app, and add them to your question.

Comment: What's the error? Please also responde with @.